# Missing DOMDocument in PHP on virtual machine

Tags: php, vagrant, domdocument

I've a vagrant box ( Scotch box ) and I updated to PHP 7 in `vagrant ssh`, now I'm missing the DOMDocument class.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml

sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

commands installs the module but I can't see it with `php -m`. Is necessary to recompile PHP?

Comment: `php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'` to see what config file it loaded, then check that file to ensure it loads the xml extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong command, `sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom` installed the module correctly. `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml` was the wrong package, in fact I don't get the link between the two.